# How to handle incoming SoapFault message

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to write to write a webservice to which one of the third party application will send the response for my requests.We have four types of responses CreateResponse, GetResponse, SetResponse, DeleteResponse. If the execution of the request fails the third pary will send  SoapFault message.
How to handle this incoming SoapFault in my webservice

```
`import javax.jws.WebService; 
import javax.jws.HandlerChain;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingType;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding;
@WebService(targetNamespace ="http://schemas.shaik.com/cai3g1.2/")
@HandlerChain(file = "handler.xml")
public class MyFirstWebService {
@WebMethod(operationName = "CreateResponse")
public void sendRequest() {
}
@WebMethod(operationName = "GetResponse")
public void sendRequest1() {
}
@WebMethod(operationName = "SetResponse")
public void sendRequest2() {
}
@WebMethod(operationName = "DeleteResponse")
public void sendRequest3() {
}
@WebMethod(operationName = "Fault")
public void sendRequest4() {
}
@WebMethod(operationName = "Cai3gFault")
public void sendRequest5() {
}
}
```

`

Comment: do you consider namespaces to be the same as packages? Of course you have tons of different packages at the same time in any webservice. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is definitely possible. Just define the right bindings and packages for it and you should be set to go.

Comment: How do we define the binindings?can you please provide a small example

Answer (score 0):

> which 4 operations are defined under one namespace and the 5th
>   operation under a different namespace

The namespace is (should be?) common for the whole service. Working with the code-first approach you can image it as have your method in a different package than the rest.

However - you may expose 5 services (or 2 services, one with 4 operations), in two distinct packages (or specify the namespace in the annotation).

Comment: Fault operation is defined under one namespace and the rest four under one namespace